# Connect two networks with OpenVPN

Tags: networking, iptables, vpn, openvpn, tunneling

I am trying to connect two networks together via OpenVPN.

Gateways can ping each other, however they cannot access other computers on the network they're joining. Logs don't show any errors, and the connection is established.

What am I missing here? Seems like many are having this issue for various reasons, but after 50+ tries I gave up and decided to ask :)

**Network 1:**

`dev tun
port 1194
ifconfig 10.8.222.40 10.8.222.41
route 10.2.1.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun
user nobody
group nobody
secret /etc/openvpn/static.key`

`ip route
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0
10.0.1.0/27 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.9
10.2.1.0/24 via 10.8.222.41 dev tun0
10.3.0.0/24 via 10.3.0.2 dev tun2
10.3.0.2 dev tun2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.3.0.1
10.8.222.41 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.222.40
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.42.1`

**Network 2**

`dev tun
port 1194
remote my_ext_ip 1194
ifconfig 10.8.222.41 10.8.222.40
route 10.0.0.0 255.254.0.0 vpn_gateway
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun
user nobody
group nobody
secret /etc/openvpn/static.key`

`ip route
default via 10.2.1.1 dev eth0
10.0.0.0/15 via 10.8.222.40 dev tun0
10.2.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.2.1.9
10.8.222.40 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.222.41
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.42.1
172.27.224.0/22 dev as0t0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.27.224.1
172.27.228.0/22 dev as0t1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.27.228.1
172.27.232.0/22 dev as0t2  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.27.232.1
172.27.236.0/22 dev as0t3  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.27.236.1`

**Update:**

Here's what I have iptables-wise:

**Both networks:**
`iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT`

**Network 1:**
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s "10.0.0.0/15" -o "eth0" -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 10.0.0.0/15 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT`

**Network 2:**
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s "10.2.1.0/24" -o "eth0" -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 10.2.1.0/24 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT`

\

**Update 2:**

**Entering tunnel:** `# tcpdump -i tun0
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 65535 bytes
01:01:15.181262 IP ip-10-8-222-41.ec2.internal > ip-10-0-1-5.ec2.internal: ICMP echo request, id 28767, seq 1, length 64`

**Exiting tunnel:** `# tcpdump -i tun0
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 65535 bytes
01:03:44.304930 IP 10.8.222.41 > 10.0.1.5: ICMP echo request, id 28784, seq 1, length 64`

**Switching interfaces** `# tcpdump -i eth0
01:08:56.093291 IP 10.8.222.41 > 10.0.1.5: ICMP echo request, id 28785, seq 3, length 64`

Comment: ip forward in every opevpn server and iptable masquerade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**

tcpdump allowed me to see that the source of packets for iptables forwarding was 10.8.222.41/32

So adding

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s "10.8.222.41/32" -o "eth0" -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 10.8.222.41/32 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT`

solved the problem!

Now both gateways can ping servers in each other's network. Now I need to figure out how to permit that to all of the computers in both networks, but that's a different question...

Comment: Have you found a solution for "Now I need to figure out how to permit that to all of the computers in both networks, but that's a different question..."?

Answer (score 0):

So from your ip route output it looks like your

```
eth0 at Network 1 is 10.0.1.0 with mask 255.255.255.224
eth0 at Network 2 is 10.2.1.0 with mask 255.255.255.0
```

So I would edit the openvpn conf on Network 1 machine to read:

```
route 10.2.1.0 255.255.255.0  #this is the remote network I want to see
```

and the openvpn conf on Network 2 machine to read:

```
route 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.224 #this is the remote network I want to see
```

That should bring up the proper routes.  Also, don't worry about adding the vpn_gateway parameter at the end of the route line, it is not needed.  By default it will add the other end of the tunnel as the gateway.

Comment: I have used `route 10.0.0.0 255.254.0.0 vpn_gateway` because one of my machines spans another network and has an IP of 10.1.0.5 (there is another VPN connection on one side of the tunnel). I have tried your suggestion, but I still can't ping local IPs of each net, and traceroute to them gives nothing either :(

Comment: then you are going to have to troubleshoot the issue with network captures.  I would start with # tcpdump -i tun0 and do your pings.  That will tell you if the ping is even going out the tunnel.

Comment: Updated the question with tcpdump output

Comment: Your tcpdump looks good.  The ping is traversing the tunnel and exiting the eth0 interface on the other end.  Now it would seem as if device with IP 10.0.1.5 is not responding back via the same path.  You must check and see if the routing table on 10.0.1.5 points to the eth0 for packets destined to 10.8.222.41.  If they were, then you would see the return packet on your third tcpdump (eth0).